# Proving $|\tanh x-\tanh y|\leq |x-y|$ and $|\operatorname{Argsinh}x-\operatorname{Argsinh}y|\leq |x-y|$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

How to prove these two inequalities for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$\begin{align}
|\tanh x-\tanh y| &\leq |x-y| \\[4pt]
|\operatorname{Argsinh}x-\operatorname{Argsinh}y| &\leq |x-y|
\end{align}$$

Thank you.

Comment: Inclined to think of mean value theorem. In particular, show that the derivatives of hyperbolic tangent and arcsine are both bounded by $1$ on the real line.

Comment: have you a pdf or something which can help me

Comment: I have sources, but I need to know what exactly you are looking for. See, the solution to this problem is what mentioned above  : using the mean value theorem, and knowing that the derivatives of the hyperbolic tangent/arcsine are bounded by $1$. So what do you need references for : the mean value theorem, or how to differentiate/find the derivatives of the hyperbolic arcsine/tangent? (Only standard textbooks would serve as a common refference for both). Alternately, you may also look up the mean value theorem as well as the hyperbolic functions on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

- The range of $\tanh x$ is $(-1,1)\;$ and $\;(\tanh)'(x)=1-\tanh^2x$,
- $(\operatorname{Argsh})'(x)=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

Comment: I don't understand what i do with the derivative ?

Comment: @PolineSandra: Both derivatives are less tan $1$. I suppose you know the *Mean value theorem* (or its corollary, the *mean value  inequality*)?

Comment: ok i understand thank you